# How to get the file name column of a SharePoint library in InfoPath

Tags: infopath

I've got a standard document library in SharePoint (2010, although I think the version doesn't matter for this question). I'm creating an InfoPath form and want to add this library as an external data source. Now when I reach the point where I can select the columns/fields I want to query, I see some of the columns (i.e. Title) but not the file name column containing the name of the document. It's just not there in the wizard ...

As you see in the screenshot (sorry, it's from a german installation of SharePoint and InfoPath) Titel (Title) is shown but Name (Filename) isn't ...

[image]

Comment: This might sound stupid, but do see that the list of columns is a scrollable dropdownlist? I spent a couple of hours before I realised last time I did this.

Comment: @tarjeieo, thanks, but I double checked: It's neither scrollable nor a dropdownlist, there is even space below the last item ...

Comment: ok, I found this http://www.experts-exchange.com/OS/Microsoft_Operating_Systems/Server/MS-SharePoint/Q_26671091.html stating that it's not in there ... someone to disagree? any ideas for a nice workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to get the File Name Column (LinkFileName - internal name of column), you can do following:

- Create 2 connections:

  1) Connection to `SharePoint library or list` to receive current item ID (select only ID column and check the box to "Include data for the active form only")

  2) Connection to "REST Web service" with the similar URL

  > https://portal.company.com/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?XMLDATA=1&List={49C66572-E2EE-4235-B216-411A07010139}&View={DF0C0998-54B7-49BF-88B3-CA300769E0CE}&FilterField1=ID&FilterValue1=5
- Create "Form Load" Rule with 2 actions

  1) Change REST URL: Use Function to concat URL and ID from first data connection

  > concat("https://portal.company.com/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?XMLDATA=1&List={49C66572-E2EE-4235-B216-411A07010139}&View={DF0C0998-54B7-49BF-88B3-CA300769E0CE}&FilterField1=ID&FilterValue1="; ID)

  2) Query for Data: Select the second data connection

Comment: Since this doesn't need code, it is better then my own workaround. So I accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar task to implement.  I ended up adding a data source to the form library.  I can't understand the language but be sure to check, only return data for current item.  Then, return to the form, select the new data source and add the Title field to the form.  This should work.  It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete solution, but in my case, I had to get the file name and url for the item, the user chose from a drop down box in the form. So I got this informations from the lists.asmx WebService using the code from this [blog article](http://blogs.myfirstsharepoint.de/archive/2011/07/12/aus-der-praxis-%E2%80%93-bibliotheken-in-infopath-%E2%80%93oder-wo-ist-mein-filename.aspx) (article is german, but code and comments are english)

But this of course is only a solution if you use code in the InfoPath form AND need the information AFTER the user chose a file.

Comment: If someone comes around with a more fitting answer, I will accept it and drop my own answer ...